# Complex Integral in Rouah's Heston book

Tags: heston

I have a silly question regarding complex calculus, in which I'm a bit rusty at the moment. In F. Rouah's book *The Heston Model and Its Extensions in Matlab and C#* the following appears:

> Now evaluate the inner integral in Equation (3.32), as was done in (3.14). This produces
> $$\begin{align} 
> \Pi_1 & = \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi_2(u) \dfrac{e^{−i(u+i)l}}{
> i(u + i)}
> du − \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \text{lim}_{R\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi_2(u) \dfrac{e^{−i(u+i)R}}{
> i(u + i)} du\\ 
> & = I_1 − I_2. \end{align}$$
> The second integral is a complex integral with a pole at $u = −i$. The residue
> there is, therefore, $\varphi_2(−i)/i$. Applying the Residue Theorem, we obtain
> $$ I_2 = \text{lim}_{R\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \Bigg[ -2 \pi i \times  \dfrac{ \varphi_2 (−i)}{i} \Bigg] = -\varphi_2(-i).$$

I think I see the point on solving the integral using the residue theorem and how it works. However, the question that rises is: Why can't I just do the same for the first integral?

Thanks

---

**Edit:** a screenshot of that page, for completion

[image]

Comment: I suspect it has to do with taking the limit in the second integral. But it's hard (for me) to say anything more without knowing the original problem and context.

Comment: It's from chapter 3 of that book. He's proving the Gil-Pelaez inversion theorem. The book can be found online but I'm not sure if it's against SE rules to share those kind of links

Comment: I don't recommend sharing links of questionable legality. You could however post a screenshot or even better write down the main points.

Comment: Edited the question including that page from the book

Comment: Well, yes, so the inner integral in 3.32 is an indefinite integral and hence you need to take the limit which can be evaluated using the residue theorem.

Comment: Sure, my question is another though. Why can't I just use that same argument to evaluate the first integral?

Comment: Why would you use the res.thm in the first as the integration interval does not include the pole u= -i? To evaluate the second integral I think some kind of contour is used with radius R and then the limit is taken. So this contour will have the pole inside it. This is how I see it (without actually doing the calculations)

Comment: I'll try to look into this more when I have more time and give a proper answer hopefully, but I suspect the reason is as explained in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks Frido. My question comes from the fact that I think that you can also do that same contour integral in the first term. It seems like you can't (otherwise why isn't it done), but I can't come out with a mathematical argument for that.

Comment: Your doubt is completely legitimate. There is no ground for applying the residue theorem. This derivation of the book is woefully unsubstantiated and wrong. I will give you a rigorous derivation, later.

Comment: @Frido: See my proof below. The route in the book is illegitimate and unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: @Hans Thanks Hans, +1 for your derivation, agree that Rouah's text seems to complicate matters only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivation in the book is unnecessarily complicated, and plain erroneous in many places, such as taking limit of $R$. Here is a simple and direct proof.

*Proof:*
Suppose $q\in L_1(-\infty,\infty)\cap L_2(-\infty,\infty)$. This implies the Fourier transform $\hat q\in L_2(-\infty,\infty)$. This is not but needed to be stated by the book.

\begin{align}
\Pi_1&=\int_l^\infty e^xq(x)\,dx  \\
&=\bigg(\int_{-\infty}^\infty-\int_{-\infty}^l\bigg)e^xq(x)\,dx \\
&= 1-\int_{-\infty}^l dx\,e^x \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty du e^{-iux}\hat q(u) \\
&= 1- \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty du\, \hat q(u)\int_{-\infty}^l dx\,e^{(1-iu)x} \tag1\label{eq:Fb}\\
&= 1+\frac{e^l}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^\infty du\,\hat q(u)\frac{e^{-iul}}{u+i}.
\end{align}
The interchanging of the order of integration resulting in Equation \eqref{eq:Fb} holds because
$$\bigg(\int_{-\infty}^l dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty du\,e^x |e^{-iux}\hat q(u)|\bigg)^2\le \int_{-\infty}^l dx\,e^{2x}\int_{-\infty}^\infty du\,|\hat q(u)|^2 <\infty$$
by [the Cauchy-Schwardtz inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) and $\hat q\in L_2(-\infty,\infty)$ satisfying the premise of [the Fubini's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem).  $\quad\blacksquare$

Indeed, the same methodology in effect proves [the Plancherel's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem?searchToken=7x8rhliepvd3x8aqswuboru31) of which this problem is an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hans!

Answer (score 2):

More context is needed, but presumably the difference is that $\ell <0$. Since $R>0$, you can close the integral in the bottom half-plane as the expression $e^{-i(u+i)R}$ goes to zero exponentially in the bottom great semi-circle. (I assume $\varphi_2$ doesn't increase too quickly to cause a problem.) But if $\ell<0$ then the expression $e^{-i(u+i)\ell}$ increases exponentially in the bottom half-plane, so if you were to try to apply the residue theorem there, you'd get a term for the semi-circle which doesn't go to zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer p.s.! But, couldn't you close the contour for that case ($l<0$) using the upper half-plane?

Comment: It depends on $\varphi_2$ whether the integral on the semi-circle would be zero. Also, you wouldn't get the residue at $-i$ if you close in the upper half plane.

Comment: I agree on the $\varphi_2$ argument. But what I meant about the upper half plane is closing it at the $-i$ straight. Wouldn't that be possible? Sorry but I'm a bit rusty in complex calculus at the moment...

Comment: These are a lot of iffy statements. See my direct and simple proof https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/75949/6686.